# Is it safe to cast arbitrary values of the underlying type to a strongly-typed enum type?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

If I have a strongly-typed enum, with say, underlying type `int`, is it ok to cast an `int` value that does not match any enumerator to the enum type?

```
enum e1 : int { x = 0, y = 1 };
enum class e2 : int { x = 0, y = 1 };

int main() {
        e1 foo = static_cast<e1>(42); // is this UB?
        e2 bar = static_cast<e2>(42);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From n3290, 5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]:

> 10 A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted
>   to an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value
>   is within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the
>   resulting value is unspecified (and might not be in that range). [...]

*Enumeration type* comprises both those types that are declared with `enum` and those that are declared with `enum class` or `enum struct`, which the Standard calls respectively *unscoped* enumerations and *scoped* enumerations. Described in more details in 7.2 Enumeration declarations [dcl.enum].

The *values* of an enumeration type are not be confused with its *enumerators*. In your case, since the enumerations you declared all have `int` as their underlying types their range of values is the same as that of `int`: from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` (inclusive).

Since `42` has type `int` and is obviously a value of `int` the behaviour is defined.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the meaning of "enumeration values". Thanks.