# Is this warning related to enum class size wrong?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, enums

Warning:

```
src/BoardRep.h:49:12: warning: ‘BoardRep::BoardRep::Row::<anonymous struct>::a’ 
is too small to hold all values of ‘enum class BoardRep::Piece’ 
[enabled by default]
Piece a:2;
        ^
```

Enum:

```
enum class Piece: unsigned char {
    EMPTY,
    WHITE,
    BLACK
};
```

Use:

```
union Row {
    struct {
        Piece a:2;
        Piece b:2;
        Piece c:2;
        Piece d:2;
        Piece e:2;
        Piece f:2;
        Piece g:2;
        Piece h:2;
    };
    unsigned short raw;
};
```

With an `enum` I'd agree with GCC, it may have to truncate but that's because `enum`s are not really separate from integers and pre-processor definitions. However an `enum class` is much stronger. If it is not strong enough to assume ALL `Piece` values taken as integers will be between 0 and 2 inclusive then the warning makes sense. Otherwise GCC is being needlessly picky and it might be worth mailing the list to say "look, this is a silly warning"

### Incase anyone cannot see the point

You can store 4 distinct values in 2 bits of data, I only need 3 distinct values, so any enum of length 4 or less should fit nicely in the 2 bits given (and my enum does "derive" (better term?) from an unsigned type). If I had 5 or more THEN I'd expect a warning.

Comment: Why are you using an enum as the underlying type for a bit field in the first place?

Comment: @KerrekSB if I don't I'd have to define an operator allowing `unsigned short` to be assigned to by a `Piece`. I am saying here the first 2 bits of this struct shall be named `a` and shall be of type `Piece` when I deal with it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974292/is-it-safe-to-cast-arbitrary-values-of-the-underlying-type-to-a-strongly-typed-e

Comment: I have the same motivations as Alec: I want to work with typed slice of the integers (for the sake of clarity and overloading). All bitfields store a subset of the possible values (unless declared as wide as the type); subjectively, I don't want a warning as this is "a rational idiom in my programming style" (I'm porting from clang++/MacOS - no warning - to gcc/Linux) unless it wouldn't fit all the values I declared (which is a hint about what I actually want to store in the bitfield!). If anybody knows a gcc command line option which will turn off this warning specifically, please share.

Comment: @DanielMGessel please see the highly upvoted "answer"

Comment: The answer is that the warning is valid, right? But so is warning that any bitfield that smaller than the underyling type cannot hold all values that could be assigned. I use asserts to validate assignments to bitfields (if I'm worried - it's alot of asserts). Semantic issues aside, practically speaking, I want to turn off that warning without switching to clang++ or turning off all warnings. I don't see that answer here, nor do I find it anywhere else (yet). I thought another "top level question" would be redundant...

Answer (score 9):

The warning issued by `gcc` is accurate, there's no need to compose a mail to the mailing list asking them to make the warning less likely to appear.

The standard says that an enumeration with the underlying type of `unsigned char` cannot be represented by a bitfield of length `2`; even if there are no enumerations that holds such value.

---

**THE STANDARD**

The underlying value of an enumeration is valid even if there are no enum-keys corresponding to this value, the standard only says that a legal value to be stored inside an enumeration must fit inside the *underlying type*; it doesn't state that such value must be present among the *enum-keys*.

> 7.2 **Enumeration declarations** `[dcl.enum]`
>
> > <sup>7</sup> <sub>...</sub> It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. <sub>...</sub>

<sup>**Note:** the quoted section is present in both C++11, and the draft of C++14.</sup>

<sup>**Note:** wording stating the same thing, but using different terminology, can be found in C++03 under `[dcl.enum]p6`</sup>

<sup>**Note:** the entire `[decl.enum]p7` hasn't been included to preserve space in this post.</sup>

---

**DETAILS**

```
enum class E : unsigned char { A, B, C };

E x = static_cast<E> (10);
```

Above we initialize `x` to store the value `10`, even if there's no *enumeration-key* present in the enum-declaration of `enum class E` this is still a valid construct.

With the above in mind we easily deduce that `10` cannot be stored in a bit-field of length `2`, so the warning by `gcc` is nothing but accurate.. we are potentially trying to store values in our bit-field that it cannot represent.

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
enum class E : unsigned char { A, B, C };

struct A {
  E value : 2;
};
```

```
A val;

val.value = static_cast<E> (10); // OMG, OPS!?
```

Comment: It's not different for `enum class`es? The distinction is purely semantic?

Comment: @AlecTeal no, there's no difference between *scoped* and *unscoped* enumerations regarding what has been asked.

Comment: You missed the point. I now know the warning makes sense, but I have not solved my problem, nor has this post. It is as useful as a post that just contains "No." but is certainly more informative. Informative does not mean it will be useful.

Comment: @AlecTeal it answers the question stated, if you meant to ask something else you must explicitly state that when creating your question. Please see; [How to Ask - Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: But, if one only stores the enumerated values (or generally the values that will fit into the bitfield), is it supposed to work, or would there be undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> 8 For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the
>   enumeration are the values of the underlying type.

So the values of your enumeration are in the range

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min() - std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()
```

Bit field a defined as

```
Piece a:2;
```

can not hold all values of the enumeration.

If you would define an unscoped enumeration without a fixed underlying type then the range of its values would be

```
0 - 2
```

Comment: Which standard? 98, 11 or 14? - that is CERTAINLY the case for 98, as it is the case in C.

Comment: @Alec Teal Scoped enumerations were introduced in the C++ 2011

Comment: `enum` and `enum class` both default to `int` as the underlying type. Surely unscoped does not mean anonymous?

Comment: @Alec Teal There is no statement in the Standard that an unscoped enumeration has the default underlying type int. An unscoped enumeration is an enumeration without enum-key class or struct.

Comment: So is there a solution to my problem? I'm not even sure which pragmas to use to silence the warning (it just says enabled by default)

Comment: @Alec Teal As I wrote in the post you could try to use unscoped enumeration.

Comment: Doesn't work, also not specifying a type with a scoped causes a lot of errors (in that the case statements throw an exception for hitting the default case (that the value wasn't recognised) confirming that even if it isn't an `int`, it is a signed type.

Comment: @Alec Teal Scoped enumerations without specified enum-base have underlying type int.

Comment: Just established that for unscoped and scoped.

Comment: @Alec Teal For an unscoped enumeration you could write simply in the union  unsigned short a:2; and assign an enumerator of the enumeration to this bit-field because there is implicit conversion from unscoped enumeration to integral types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this warning is pointless because GCC already warns about assigning a value to a bitfield field (of enum type) that is truncated like this:

```
warning: conversion from 'Some_Enum' to 'unsigned char:2'
         changes value from '(Some_Enum)9' to '1' [-Woverflow]
```

At the location of the warning it's only relevant that all declared enumerators can be held inside the bitfield field.

The statement that other values that are in the range of the underlying integer type (but don't correspond to a declared enumerator, which btw is well-defined, in general) can't be represented by the field, if ever assigned, is technically true, but has zero entropy, as a warning.

Thus, this [warning was fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51242#c31) in GCC 9.3.

IOW, GCC 9.3 and later don't warn about such code, anymore.