# Is it possible to specify the bit width of an enum in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm exchanging packets with an embedded device and I'd really like to be able to use enums in the sub-byte parts of the packet definitions too. But I can't guess a syntax that might work and I suspect it's not possible, since I can't work out how to declare a partial-byte subtype in C++:

```
enum class communication_path_t : uint8_t  { 
    Ethernet = 0, Wifi = 1
};

typedef struct {
    communication_path_t pathByte;  // works, uses one byte
    // ... 
    // single byte split three ways
    uint8_t retryCount : 3;
    communication_path_t path : 3;  // compile error
    uint8_t deviceType : 2;
} packet_t;
```

That doesn't compile, because you can't fit an 8 bit enum into a 3 bit field. Edited in the exact error:

```
<anonymous struct>::path’ is too small to hold all values
   of ‘enum class MyNamespace::communication_path_t’ [-Werror]
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
enum class communication_path_t : uint8_t : 3 { ...
```

or

```
typedef uint8_t:3 three_bit_int_t;
enum class communication_path_t : three_bit_int_t { ...
```

Neither of those compile, and I'm having trouble finding documentation that refers to both bit fields and enums, making me suspect there is none. Before I spend hours looking, is what I'm trying to do even possible?

---

Edit: upgrading to g++-4.9 does not fix the problem. It's remarkably painless, just:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
g++-4.9 --version

g++-4.9 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2
GCC 4.9.2 released [2014-10-30]
```

Then change my build chain to use "g++-4.9" instead of "g++". Unfortunately I get the same error:

```
g++-4.9 -Dlinux -std=c++11 -pthread (...) ../common/LogPacketBreakdown.cpp
In file included from ../common/LogPacketBreakdown.cpp:12:0:
../common/PacketInfo.h:104:50: error: ‘Digiflex::<anonymous
    struct>::communicationPath’ is too small to hold all values of 
    ‘enum class Digiflex::communication_path_t’ [-Werror]
    communication_path_t communicationPath : 3;
```

Looks as though I need 5.0 and that's not in the Ubuntu experimental tools list so I'd need to build from source. I think I'll just live with the workaround for now. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Who downvoted this? We seldom see a more perfect question.

Comment: … also, kudos for using modern C++ on an embedded device.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to Delphi so it seems like a natural approach, especially when we have polyglot consumers of the embedded output (Delphi, C++, ObjectiveC and Java. For reasons, obviously). It's just easier to have everyone's code read as similarly as possible and use whatever type safety is available.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606392/is-this-warning-related-to-enum-class-size-wrong seems to argue that even an enum class based on byte can correctly be set to any value legal for a byte, regardless of whether there are enum members with those values.

Comment: Yes, an `enum : uint8` can be used just like a `uint8`, but that means it should work as a bitfield just like a `uint8` too. *Every* bitfield is defined over a subset of its type's values, that's what bitfields do.

Comment: five years later: g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20191120 (Red Hat 9.2.1-2) still does not accept this, even when C++17 is explicitly specified. The good news for me is that that is the sole remaing build environment where it doesn't work (from six options).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code you posted should be accepted by the most recent compilers. You can see this bug report where the fix should have occurred: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51242

In today's gcc, a warning should still be emitted. In clang, you should see nothing.

Comment: @CodeAbominator: The first comment includes a test case which is basically identical to your code.

Comment: Interesting, the bug is a year old and is exactly what I'm trying to do. The standard even says "A bit-ﬁeld shall have integral or **enumeration type** (3.9.1)."Unfortunately it doesn't look as though it's going to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: Another bug with more info from the standard. It seems even more likely that this should work: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56566

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to `typedef` a bitfield in C++, not even with an enumeration type.

Bitfield-ness is a property of member variable declarations, it's not supported by the type system at all.

But, your first example is perfectly fine. As Bill says, it's a GCC bug, and as the GCC developers [note](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51242#c25), it's only a warning since 2013. The workaround is to use `int path : 3;` and to convert the enumeration values, or don't use an `enum` at all.

Answer (score 0):

It works at least from g++ 4.8 on debian, so I assume also on ubuntu.

Compiler give only a warning, error in this case was cased by *-Werror* compiler option. It is a good idea to configure *-Werror* for *overflow* as this will be reported when assigning an enum value that doesn't fit a bitfield.