# Type cast failed in switch for enum with restricted storage

Tags: c++, g++, switch-statement, bit-fields, enum-class

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
enum class confirm {yes};

struct item
{
  confirm s:4; // (1) limiting storage size required
};

int main()
{
  item itm;

  itm.s = confirm::yes; // (2) OK

  switch (itm.s)
  {
    case confirm::yes: // (3) Failure, need static data cast here?
      break;
  }
}
```

produces error:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: could not convert ‘yes’ from ‘confirm’ to ‘int’
 case confirm::yes:
               ^
```

while compiling with *g++* but compiled fine by *clang++*. **Why** assignment marked by (2) possible but *case* clause marked by (3) not?

Warning about `too small storage` is of [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401851/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-bit-width-of-an-enum-in-c11)

Comment: Would "this is a gcc bug" be a sufficient answer?  (naturally with evidence that it should be allowed)

Comment: @Yakk: there is doubt

Comment: @dyp: thanks for tagging, but a question is specific for `enum class` —C++11 only; no such problem in previous standards

Comment: I had to choose between the C++11 tag and some other tags (5 tags max); my reasoning was this: [enum-class] implies C++11, so it is clear from the tags that this is >= C++11. The three [switch-statement], [bit-fields] and [enum-class] describe the issue in [g++]. I guess the [c++11] tag will become redundant in some time anyway, I see various questions already accepting C++11 answers w/o the [c++11] tag.

Comment: @dyp it looks like a bug to me and the latest gcc allows this with only a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a gcc bug, we can see this works [in the latest gcc version](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4mXTpXfryqLFmeA2):

From the draft C++11 standard section `6.4.2` *[stmt.switch]*:

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a
>   class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to
>   integral or enumeration type exists (12.3). [...] Integral promotions
>   are performed. Any statement within the switch statement can be
>   labeled with one or more case labels as follows:
>
> ```
> case constant-expression :
> ```
>
> **where the constant-expression shall be a converted constant expression** (5.19) of the promoted type of the switch condition.

converted constant expression is covered in section `5.19` which says:

> [...]A converted constant expression of type T is a literal constant expression, implicitly converted to type T,
>   where the implicit conversion (if any) is permitted in a literal constant expression and the implicit conversion
>   sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5),
>   and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4). [ Note: such expressions may be used
>   as case expressions (6.4.2), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), and as integral or
>   enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3). —end note ] [...]

Perhaps this is related to [defect report 1767: Scoped enumeration in a switch statement](http://wg21.link/cwg1767). So perhaps it was forcing a promotion to int and then the comparison in the case would fail.