# gcc suppress warning "too small to hold all values of"

Tags: c++, gcc, enums, bit-fields, suppress-warnings

I need to use scoped enums so that I can pass them as specific types to our serialiser. I have given explicit integer values for the enum members of `Enum1`.

I have put two scoped enums matching the description above into a bitfield thus

```
enum class Enum1 {
    value1 = 0x0,
    value2 = 0x1,
    value3 = 0x2
};
enum class Enum2 {
    value1 = 0x0,
    value2,
    value3,
 // ...
    value14
};

struct Example {
    Enum1 value1 : 2;
    Enum2 value2 : 6;
}
```

Now wherever I use the `Example` type, I get the warning "'Example::value1' is too small to hold all values of 'Enum1'", and similarly for `Enum2`. Note that this is not the case for the values we have defined and we are not concerned *at all* with values outside of these.

This is quite a serious distraction in our build process - the project is large and complex and we don't want to have to scan through many of these warnings (and there are many).

I had a look for a GCC (G++) flag to disable the specific warning. Is there one that I can pass on the command line? Ideally, I would use the warning pragma to disable it locally, if possible.

There is little scope for changing the code structure at this point, but we could really use these spurious warnings removed.

Edit: Added scoped enums with identifiers changed.

Comment: if Enum1 contains values more than 3, then it will not fit on 2 bits

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Enum1` and `Enum2`?

Comment: @nikniknik2016: It doesn't

Comment: @Angew: Nope, company code, sorry!

Comment: @jsren Then create an articial [mcve] reproducing the same issue, and post that. We cannot help with code we cannot see.

Comment: @Angew I will, thank you. I was hoping for a compiler flag, as a general-case solution. Hence the lack of example.

Comment: While I can't figure out the status of it, there's this [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51242)

Comment: @nos: While this bug opened as a compiler error about scoped enums and bitfields (now fixed), it is kept opened because they didn't figure out the best way to disable the warning. The last post is about 2 years ago, so they probably just forgot about it.

Comment: Lol, this code causes Internal Compiler Error in MSVC 2017 (I accidentally had godbolt set to that from last time)

Comment: The range of a 2-bit ssigned bitfield is `[-2, 1]`. The value `0x2` is actually out of range for `Enum1::value1`.  (And it is confusing that `Example` has the same field name as the enumerator values it stores)

Comment: I am facing the same problem and this warning seems to be completely pointless and vexing. Following the same logic, the compiler should've warned me that  `i` is too small to hold all values of `int` when I write something like `int i : 10;`

Comment: Similar question: [Is this warning related to enum class size wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22606392/427158)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that an scoped enum always has an integral underlying type. By default, it is `int` but you can change it to any other integral type, such as `unsigned char`.

Unfortunately you cannot change the underlying type to a bit-field, as they are not real C++ types.

You could try disabling the warning, but a quick skim through the G++ code reveals these lines (`gcc/cp/class.c:3468`):

```
  else if (TREE_CODE (type) == ENUMERAL_TYPE
           && (0 > (compare_tree_int
                    (w, TYPE_PRECISION (ENUM_UNDERLYING_TYPE (type))))))
    warning_at (DECL_SOURCE_LOCATION (field), 0,
                "%qD is too small to hold all values of %q#T",
                field, type);
```

The key here is the call to `warning_at(...)` instead of `warning(OPT_to_disable_the_warning, ...)`. So currently there is no option to disable it. Except recompiling the compiler yourself!

For what it is worth CLang++-3.7.1 does not warn about it.

Comment: Cheers. Tbh I think it's a useful warning. If it had a better description. And really only the first time. My major issue with it is the fact that it occurs _multiple times_ for both each field and for each compilation unit. Despite using only one g++ invocation. What's the best way of prodding the devs about this?

Answer (score 3):

As I recall, an enum with a declared underlying type can hold any value of that type, regardless of what enumeration constants are defined.  Since you can say

```
val= enum2{148}
```

and expect it to work properly, the warning seems correct for that case.  You are not declaring a base type, and historically this means that the enum is only guaranteed to be big enough to hold the range of values given by the lowest through highest enumeration constant.  So I would expect no warning here.  Maybe the new `enum class` also expects a full range even though the underlying type was automatically determined (or the compiler thinks it does)?  You might try using a pure old-syntax enum and see if that works any differently.

Comment: The enums in the question don't have a declared underlying type. But actually the rule is that if there is *fixed underlying type* then any value of the underlying type is a valid enumerator value.  And scoped enums (i.e. `enum class`) always have a fixed underlying type, which is `int` if not otherwise specified

Answer (score 2):

Emitting this warning is a bug, because all declared enumerator (values) in fact can be held by the bitfield fields.

Like with traditional enums, a variable of scoped enum type still can hold any value of its underlying type, even ones that don't correspond to a declared enumerator.

However, warning about this like this

```
warning: 'some bitfield field' is too small to hold all values of 'enum class FOO'
```

is quite pointless because assigning a too large value as in

```
Example x;
x.value1 = Enum1(8);
```

already generates a `-Woverflow` warning.

---

Consequently, GCC [fixed this warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51242#c31) in version 9.3.

FWIW, Clang never warned about.

---

IOW, to suppress this warning in GCC you have to upgrade to GCC version 9.3 or later.

Answer (score -1):

For other people like me who end up here from search:

This problem only applies to C++11 scoped enums. If you need bitfield enums, old style enums without explicit storage size work fine:

```
enum Enum1 {
    Enum1_value1 = 0x0,
    Enum1_value2 = 0x1,
    Enum1_value3 = 0x2
};
enum Enum2 {
    Enum2_value1 = 0x0,
    Enum2_value2,
    Enum2_value3,
 // ...
    Enum2_value14
};

struct Example {
    Enum1 value1 : 2;
    Enum2 value2 : 6;
}
```

Comment: It also applies to underlying-type-fixed **unscoped** enums such as `enum Enum1 : uint8_t`, when comping with GCC < 9.3.