# Restrict enum class number of bits

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++14, I would like to restrict the total number of bits held by an enum class:

```
enum class InstalledCapacity : uint8_t{
  None,
  One_1000uF,
  Two_1000uF,
  Three_1000uF,
  One_1F,
  One_3_3F,
  Reserved2,
  Invalid
};

using HarvestingCapability = uint8_t;

typedef struct {
  InstalledCapacity installed_capacity : 3;
  HarvestingCapability harversting_capability_x_15mW : 5;
}EnergyInfo;
```

This does not seem to work, and I get the following warning:

```
eeprom_metadata.h:51:42: warning: '<anonymous struct>::installed_capacity' is too small to hold all values of 'enum class InstalledCapacity'
   InstalledCapacity installed_capacity : 3;
                                          ^
```

Since I only have 7 values in my `InstalledCapacity` enum class, I would expect to be able to only use 3 bits for it.

What am I doing wrong, is this even possible? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this warning related to enum class size wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606392/is-this-warning-related-to-enum-class-size-wrong)

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is wrong, the compiler is just commenting that 3 bits is too small to hold all possible values of the enum, which can be as large as 8 bits. Just because all of your named enumeration values can fit into 3 bits doesn't mean that all the possible values of `InstalledCapacity` can fit into the bitset. A value of `255` is perfectly valid for the enum, but cannot fit into your bitset.

Comment: I see, it does make sense. If I use the "treat warnings as errors" flag, this is an error which I for sure do not want. Is there any way to circumvent it?

Comment: This issue seems to have been discussed at some length in various circles, I would suggest perhaps either disabling this specific warning or disabling it for the specific file. See this question (may be a dupe, my apologies) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606392/is-this-warning-related-to-enum-class-size-wrong